# rvm install 2.6.2 is not working in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I have installed rvm in my machine.
I want to install ruby-2.6.2 but `rvm install 2.6.2` it shows an following error
Please help me to fix this

```
xx@LAPTOP-U5HPCQ9V:~$ rvm -v
rvm 1.29.12 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]
xx@LAPTOP-U5HPCQ9V:~$ rvm install 2.6.2
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm_io.global.ssl.fastly.net/binaries/ubuntu/20.04/x86_64/ruby-2.6.6.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Installing requirements for ubuntu.
Updating system...
Installing required packages: libgmp-dev, libssl-dev....
Error running 'requirements_debian_libs_install libgmp-dev libssl-dev',
please read /usr/share/rvm/log/1634551925_ruby-2.6.6/package_install_libgmp-dev_libssl-dev.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
2. Add those lines in `sources.list` file

> ```
> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
> deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
> deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
> deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
> deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
> deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
> ```

3. `sudo apt update`
4. `sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev`
5. `rvm install 2.6.2`